# How to join 2 different SQL databases from 2 websites on same server?

Tags: sql, database, join

I have 2 websites with different framework (Codeigniter and Kohana). I installed Kohana website as subdomain and Codeigniter website as main website on **SAME SERVER**, and they both have different database. I try to make signup and login user information are the same for both website, and user dont have to login again when going to subdomain website.

1. What i am trying to do is when users go to home page signup for an account, then that information could pass into those two different databases. So when they log in those 2 websites, they could log in using the same login information.
2. Users dont have to log in again if they already log into either website.

Can anyone suggest me a way, maybe share some documentations about this coding or show me how to do it?

Thank you so much

Comment: if they are on same server they can be used in queries with join..also recommendations are offtopic

Comment: If i know i won't ask this question, you already voted for negative.

Comment: No harm to make some search on same topics,yes opted to close as well

Comment: You simply need to ensure that the login code in both websites refer to the _same_ security database.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: hi, SQL database. Kohana using SQL and Codeigniter using SQLi. Thank you

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, the thing is the main user login in both system in main website (Codeigniter), and how do i get subdomain website to get that information from main website? Thanks

Comment: The actual data defining the users is in two databases right now, correct? You need to alter your to only store and read from one database. I can't tell you how to do that - it's your code. Can you find the class/piece of code the writes users the the database and checks logins? Maybe you should use OAuth instead of internal databases.

Comment: Yes, they are in two database right now and same server. The coding of two frameworks are using simple login, model view controller. Yes, after researching about OAuth, OAuth should be one of the right way to do it. Thank you so much for this suggestion. The only thing is i am just a beginning developer, i need to learn how to integrate OAuth into the websites right?

Comment: Also, I am not sure there will be Oauth login for Kohana since Kohana is discontinue. Can i ask? Is it safe to use OAuth login? Thanks

Comment: I can't help any further. You need to read OAuth documentation and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could join using queries. About login using same information and when you log in 1 website, other website is automatically logged in. This you might need to use Json authentication.

Utility, if he knows, i will not ask that question. And did you even read number 1 and 2 more specific that he is asking

Comment: Thank you so much, i researched online and there is some information about using Json authentication but there is no document saying more specific.

Comment: exactly nobody ask questions if they know them dear @Andy .. well "share some documentations about this coding or show me how to do it" is not a good way at stackoverflow also the question has a heading that is not explained in details about the question !\